# What would be the complement of $L =\{a^{n}b^{m}a^{n}b^{m} | n,m \geq 1\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I understand the complement of L would be all the strings not in L, but I'm having a hard time writing down the structure of all the strings not in L.

Comment: Are you sure this language is context-free?  I haven't worked through the pumping lemma rigorously, but I don't think this language is context-free --- see [this wiki section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Examples_of_languages_that_are_not_context_free) and how it suggests a language containing $a^nb^na^nb^n$ is not context-free.

Answer (score 1):

As well as all sentences which are not in the form $a^ib^ja^kb^l$, there's the set $\{a^ib^ja^kb^l\mid i\ne k \lor j \ne l\}$. The two inequalities are not mutually exclusive, but it should be clear that only if both inequalities are false (i.e. both equalities would be true) would the sentences be in $L$.